# What do I do to solve the Witchess puzzles?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

The Witchess set has these puzzles, and I get that you make paths of a sort by clicking on sections, but I can't really determine what I am supposed to do, or what logic I am supposed to use to solve these. The couple I solved I did mostly by clicking about randomly.

Were there instructions that I missed that would help? How am I supposed to tackle these?

Answer (score 1):

There were no instructions that you missed. You're "supposed" to figure it out through experimentation with the tutorial puzzles, but if you don't want to do that, the rules are explained [on the wiki](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Witchess_Puzzles).